# Avoiding child rerender when parent runs setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

lHello everyone, here is the problem.

We have a grid component with some filtering enabled. When the filtering is applied, if a certain callback-prop exists, it is called with the filtered data  as an argument.

The problem is this. If said datagrid is wrapped by a parent component and the parent component saves the filtered data in it's state, it causes the parent to rerender, but also the datagrid. However, when the datagrid renders it runs it's filtering logic, which causes the callback(which is `setState()` call) to run.

So, to avoid the loop I introduced a variable to the parent component class and save the data there, but it doesn't seem so good to me.

Another option would be redux, just add a new action and dispatch it when the filtering runs.

Any other ideas?

Comment: A common way to prevent rerenders is to use React.PureComponent, React.memo or shouldComponentUpdate. Consider providing the code for your problem if it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: The child shouldn't re-render when the parent uses `setState()`. Only when its props change

Comment: what if you apply filter callback not in grid's `render()` but in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`? By now if you grid changes its state -> `render()` should be called -> filtering is re-applied. That I believe should be also avoid - since input data and filter callbacks are the same

Answer (score 0):

Since you're also asking for other ideas, may I suggest React hooks. They allow finer-grained control, such as multiple states, [reducers](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), [memoized callbacks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), effects that are [only called when inputs change](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect), etc.